# lean tools/methods to make a browser addon available in all major browsers?

Tags: firefox-addon, greasemonkey, firefox-addon-sdk, browser-addons

are there any simple tools/methods to make a browser extension available in all major browsers without bothering with each too much?

Else, will the code tend to be be easier/completely portable using a mighty language like java instead of javascript and therefore less browser sepecific code?

Yet for all browsers (Chrome, Firefox, [ie, Opera, Safari or more]) 
i saw http://www.besttoolbars.net/products/addon_framework/download/,
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_toolbar#Cross-Browser_Toolbar_Development , etc.

but dont know if any of these are completely free?

and if they allow something for http head/status code request to external domains? 
(like wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest does, which won't workout with an injected javascript alone as of cross-site-scriting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All browsers use their own api's to create their extensions, but there are some services that claim (not from my experience) to make the extension process easier to make them available for multiple browsers. One i've heard is [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/). Check it out and see if it fits your needs.